# Bash script failed to Compare SHA-512 salted hashes. Gets wrong output

Tags: bash, sha, sha512

I was able to fix the error not being able to use `*` as part of the `LIST`. However i was not able to compare and get the desired output of the password.

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST=(W 2 v '*' %)
encr="Cd9AjUI4nGglIcP3MByrZUnu.hHBJc7.eR0o/v0A1gu0/6ztFfBxeJgKTzpgoCLptJS2NnliZLZjO40LUseED/"

salt="8899Uidd"
for i in "${LIST[@]}"
  do
   for j in "${LIST[@]}"
    do
    for k in "${LIST[@]}"
     do
      for l in "${LIST[@]}"
        do
        for a in "${LIST[@]}"
            do
            echo -n "$i$j$k$l$a "

   test="mkpasswd -m SHA-512 $i$j$k$l$a -s $salt | cut -d"$" -f4"
    if [ "$test" == "$encr" ] ; then
            echo " Password is: $i$j$k$l$a"
            exit
        fi
        done
       done
      done
    done
done

#error comparing
```

The Output should be `Password is: W2v*%`, but it came out as `%%%%%`

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Please excuse the mess, still have the bad habit.

Comment: `test="...."` -> `test="$(....)"`. Also `$` is special inside `"` quotes, use `'` to handle dollar or escape it. So `"$"` -> `"\$"` or `'$'`

Comment: Also, put double-quotes around `$i$j$k$l$a` or it'll sometimes morph into a list of matching filenames.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is working now :D

Comment: Post your correct code as an answer and then accept your answer (after 48? hrs) to gain reputation points here on S.O. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of tweaking here and there. Here we have a fixed one :D

Hope its working for you guys as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST1=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)
LIST2=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
LIST3=(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)
LIST4=("~" "@" "#" "$" "%" "^" "*" "_" "+" "-" "=" "{" "}" "[" "]" "?" ";" ":")
LIST5=("~" "@" "#" "$" "%" "^" "*" "_" "+" "-" "=" "{" "}" "[" "]" "?" ";" ":")
encr="Cd9AjUI4nGglIcP3MByrZUnu.hHBJc7.eR0o/v0A1gu0/6ztFfBxeJgKTzpgoCLptJS2NnliZLZjO40LUseED/"

salt="8899Uidd"
for i in "${LIST1[@]}"
  do
   for j in "${LIST2[@]}"
    do
    for k in "${LIST3[@]}"
     do
      for l in "${LIST4[@]}"
        do
        for a in "${LIST5[@]}"
            do
            echo -n "$i$j$k$l$a"

   test="$(mkpasswd -m SHA-512 "$i$j$k$l$a" -s $salt | cut -d"$" -f4)"
    if [ "$test" == "$encr" ] ; then
            echo " Password is: $i$j$k$l$a"
            exit
        fi
        done
       done
      done
    done
done
```

**P.S:** I overdid with the list. You can combine the list into one.